# Can't make native call programmatically in ios10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I tried to make a cell call by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:37146903"]]` on `iOS10` but it's not successful. Please help me out if you have any experience for this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[openURL(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl?language=objc) is deprecated in iOS 10.

> The new UIApplication method openURL:options:completionHandler:, which
>   is executed asynchronously and calls the specified completion handler
>   on the main queue (this method replaces openURL:).

**New method in iOS 10:**

```
- (void)openURL:(NSURL*)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options
  completionHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL success))completion
```

Like,

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Example:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:37146903"];

if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 10.0){

  if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
    [application openURL:URL options:@{}
       completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
      NSLog(@"Open %@: %d",scheme,success);
    }];
  } else {
    BOOL success = [application openURL:URL];
    NSLog(@"Open %@: %d",scheme,success);
  }


}
else{

  bool can = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:URL];

  if(can){

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];

  }

}
```

Read in more detail here:

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:37146903"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

`openURL` is deprecated in ios 10

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake that makes app can't make cell call.
I called CXStartCallAction before opening url to make cell call. I removed calling CXStartCallAction. My issue is resolved.